# sidebar problem please see the below code

Tags: laravel

I added the sidebar for this code that should be display in the right site but when I reload the sidebar is visible in the left.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-3 pull-left">
        <!-- Jumbotron -->
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>{{$company->name}}</h1>
            <p class="lead">{{$company->description}}</p>
            <!--  <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Get started today</a></p>  -->
        </div>

        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row" style="background: white; margin: 10px; ">
            @foreach($company->projects as $project)
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h2>{{ $project->name }}</h2>
                    <p class="text-danger">{{ $project->description  }}</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/projects/{{$project->id}}" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pull-right">
        <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
            <h4>About</h4>
            <p>
                Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet
                fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-module">
            <h4>Archives</h4>
            <ol class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#">March 2014</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">February 2014</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">January 2014</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">December 2013</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">November 2013</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">October 2013</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">September 2013</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">August 2013</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">July 2013</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">June 2013</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">May 2013</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">April 2013</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-module">
            <h4>Elsewhere</h4>
            <ol class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

location of the sidebar is in the wrong location

Comment: A screenshot would probably go a long way here.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If so, what version?

Comment: yes i use bootstrap version 3.3

Answer (score 2):

Put columns inside row class and put row inside container/container-fluid class

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-3">
      // content goes here
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pull-right">
      //sidebar goes here
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```